# Sharepoint: access subsite page contact from workflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a work flow that will send an email to the users in the contact field for the page that the initial link was followed from.

In other words, a user clicks a link on page `../top/sub/pages/page1.aspx` which takes them to a form here: `..top/lists/feedback/newform.aspx`. Once they submit the form on the top level page it starts a workflow (at `..top/lists/feedback/`) which will email the users in the meta data for the referrer page (`../top/sub/pages/page1.aspx`) and finish by deleting the feedback item.

My problem lies in trying to email the correct user. I have tried to make a work-flow on the sub-site, but it seems like the work-flow has ZERO access outside of its directory.

My next idea would be to try and send the user as a parameter (as part of the form) using a script, but I'm unsure of how to access the information I need.

How would I access the page's contact user? Am I even on the right track?

ps. I dont have access to the server and therefore am unable to use visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there might be some dirty workaround.

1. add a hidden field to you top/lists/feedback/
2. add a delegate control that stores the contact on the page the user came from i.e. in the    user session (or somewhere in SharePoint or in DB) and place the control on the pages ../top/sub/pages/ (or place it everywhere but make it work only on the pages)
3. add an itemeventreceiver in the list ..top/lists/feedback/ that grabs what the delegate control saved and inserts it into the hidden field in the item that is created in the ..top/lists/feedback/newform.aspx
4. use the hidden field in the wotkflow.

I hope you can either accept it or generate you own idea reading my answer.
Good luck!

Comment: +1, but I don't know if this would be an answer so I'll leave it open for a bit longer. Thanks for the idea, thats generally the way I've been going. Ill have to look into the control / delegates your talking about. (my share point training = here's your desk)